# Mongoose How To Query Within Date Range And Extract Highest Values For Each Day?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

How do I design a query with mongoose/mongodb to search within a date range and extract the highest price values for each day within that range?  Right now, the only way I know how to do this is to execute a query within a date range and then process the results to pull the highest prices for each day.  But this seems like a common need, so I'm wondering if it's possible to do it all in the query:

Here is my model, it gives a few different things that can be used in the query.  The `date` property is a Date type, and the `day` property is a string type.  the `day` property is in this format `day: "02/11/2014"`.  The `price` property is a Number data type, and it is in this format: `price: 114.61`

```
// Price Schema
var PriceSchema = new Schema({
    full_date: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true
    },
    day: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    }
});
```

**Here is the query within a date range, but can I do something akin to a forEach date return highest price?**

```
Price.find({ date: { $lt: end, $gt: start }}, function(err, prices) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.jsonp(poolprices);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Was there something in the answer that did not address your question here?

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to use the [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) for this:

```
Price.aggregate([
    // Match the date range
    { "$match": { "date": { "$lt": end, "$gt": start} } },

    // Change document with date to a value just for the day
    { "$project":{ 
        "date": {
           "year": { "$year": "$date"}, 
           "month": { "$month": "$date" }, 
           "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$date"}
        },
        "price": 1
    }},

    // Sort everything (descending so highest price per day is on top)
    { "$sort": { "date.year": -1, "date.month": -1, "date.day": -1, "price": -1 }},

    // Group per day (now as a nice string), and keep the first price (highest)
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": {
            "$concat": [{ "$substr": ["$date.year", 0, 4] },
            "-",
           { "$substr": ["$date.month", 0, 2]},
            "-", 
           { "$substr": ["$date.day", 0, 2]}]
        },
        "price": { "$first": "$price"}
    }},

    // Make field names nicer
    { "$project": { "_id":0, "day": "$_id", "price": 1 } }

],
function(err,result) {
    //process here
})
```

So the results will only have 1 price per day within your range and there is no need to loop the results programatically.

It's a nice little operation that makes use of the [Date Operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) to break up the date field, then makes use of [$substr](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) and [$concat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) in order to return a better value for your results. Considering you now know what you can do here you might rethink some of the fields in your schema as well.